# ¿Como Compartir o enviar objetos de un war a otro war usando JSP y Wildfly 10?

Tags: java, jsp, aplicación-web, wildfly, single-sign-on

Actualmente tengo un objeto Usuario el cual creo en el War1 y deseo que cuando llame al War2 pueda obtener ese mismo objeto en el War2.

Las aplicaciones deben estar en EARs diferentes por tal motivo no puedo pasar el objeto por session. ¿De que otra forma puedo pasar objetos entre distintos wars desplegados en un mismo servidor de aplicaciones?

Actualmente estoy desarrollando en JSP y utilizo Wildfly 10 como servidor de aplicaciones. Gracias

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

1-  Consultamos el USUARIO y lo guardamos en SESSION.

2-  Al tener todo en un mismo EAR, puedo tener la SESSION COMPARTIDA por lo tanto puedo usarla en todos los wars que lo necesite.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

La idea es separar los componentes. Toda la parte transaccional en un EAR y el Login y demás wars independientes con el fin de cuando se haga un cambio solo se despliegue el componente modificado y no toda la aplicación.

Para resolver eso necesito configurar single sign on (SSO) en mi servidor Wildfly 10

Answer (score 1):

No puedes pasar objetos entre war's, realmente no pasas nada entre wars, un war es simplemente una aplicacion web empaquetada para ser ejecutada en un servidor.

Para compartir datos entre aplicaciones simplemente usa una base de datos común en las 2 aplicaciones y guarda allí los objetos que necesites.

Lo que tienes que hacer es un ejemplo típico de CAS o SSO o sea login común para varias aplicaciones, tu solo creas el usuario una vez y a medida que tiene que ir accediendo a mas aplicaciones solo tienes que darle permisos.

```
APP1           APP2
  |\          /  |
  | \        /   |
  |  \      /    |
  |   \    /     |
  v    v  v      v
BBDD1  BBDD    BBDD2
     USUARIOS
        ^
        |
        |
       APP3 ----> BBDD3
```

Comment: Hola gracias por responder, podrías por favor colocar un ejemplo de como hacerlo usando Wildfly 10 y JSP?

Comment: No, porque no tiene nada que ver ni el servidor (wildfly) ni jsp!! aqui entran jdbc y la base de datos que uses!! Por favor lee mi respuesta y pregunta si tienes dudas, quizas no es la respuesta que esperabas o quizas no entiendes el problema. Pregunta sin pudor, pero piensa en que **los obetos no existen fuera de la ejecucion de cada aplicacion si no son persistidos**

Comment: Hola @Jordi Nuevamente gracias por responder. Estuve leyendo y lo que me explicaste es tal cual lo que necesito, existe un proyecto CAS Server con SSO el cual se puede usar y adaptar a mi aplicación, el problema es que lo descargue y veo que tiene muchísimos módulos y no se cual usar o por donde empezar. También leí que Single-Sign-ON se puede configurar en los servidores de aplicaciones. La pregunta mia ahora es: Podrías darme un ejemplo de como usar CAS en mi aplicación o de como configurar SSO en Wildfly. Gracias...

Comment: sin problema, pero para ello, edita tu pregunta y muestra como tienes configurada la base de datos, como te digo, el servidor, si las aplicaciones ya estan funcionando, tiene poco que ver. Para decirlo facil y rapido: **tienes que crear una nueva conexion de base de datos comun para las dos aplicaciones y hacer que el login ataque allí.**

Comment: Hola @Jordi gracias por responder. Acabo de modificar mi pregunta con el fin de que sea un poco mas fácil de comprender.. Gracias.